# Ошибка left of '.question' must have class/struct/union

Tags: c++, build-error

Но я  же правильно передаю, через . , где я  туплю?

```
 void JSONVisitor::visit(const Task* task) const
 {
    if (task != nullptr)
    {
         std::unique_ptr<QJsonObject> jsonObject = std::make_unique<QJsonObject>();
         (*jsonObject)["classType"] = ClassType::TASK;
         (*jsonObject)["question"] = task.question();
         (*jsonObject)["answer"] = task.answer();
         (*jsonObject)["numPoints"] = task.numPoints();
    }
 }
```

Comment: `task` - это указатель, соответственно должно быть `->`. Вам стоит начать использовать какую-нибудь IDE.

Comment: да, действительно, там нужен `->` а не точка, так как это указатель. Ну или можно в скобках разыменовать указатель и после скобок уже ставить вам привычныю точку. Но насчет IDE не совсем согласен с предыдущим комментатором - это не обязательно, я, например, программирую в `vim` и не испытываю каких либо проблем, которые решали бы только с помощью IDE (хотя `vim` у меня хорошенько расширен за счет плагинов).

Comment: @VTT error: C2027: use of undefined type 'Task'

Comment: error: C2227: left of '->question' must point to class/struct/union/generic type

Comment: все  я просто  забыл додать #include "Task.h"

Comment: @VTT следущая  ошибка :  cannot convert argument 1 from 'const Component *' to 'const Test *'   я  так  делаю : visit(test->child(childIndex)) Test наследник  от Component;

Comment: Добавить каст (приведение типов).

Comment: @nick_n_a навидите пример если не сложно. плиз dynamic_cast?

Comment: Необходимости в апкастинге указывает, что скорее всего вы делаете что-то принципиально не так.

Comment: @VTT *даункастинге

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ,    вы пытаетесь поправить, но ошибаетесь вы сами, так что удалите свой комментарий,  в целях не запутать читателей

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Речь идет о преобразовании указателя на родитель в указатель на потомка. [Это называется downcasting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting). Если бы речь шла об обратном, т.е. о преобразовании указателя на потомок в указатель на родителя, то это называлось бы upcasting. Второе совершенно нормально, а первое иногда считается признаком плохой архитектуры. Разве я не прав?